# Python printing text after printing a variables

Tags: python, variables, printing

So I wanna print some text after i print my variables like this:

```
print('Blablabla' var ' blablabla')
```

Right now it looks like this:

```
 print('The enemey gets hit for %d' % damage)
```

I wanna print the word "Hitpoints" after I've printed the damage variable.

Comment: `print('The enemy gets hit for {} hitpoints'.format(damage))`...  You could also use `%d`, but `str.format` is the new method.

Comment: This is a confusing question.  It seems hard to understand what's difficult about putting `Hitpoints ` into the format string itself.  Can you explain what confused you about the format string?  Is the some question about the `%` string operator?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just include the hitpoints:

```
print('The enemey gets hit for %d hitpoints' % damage)
```

The formatting operator `%` is very powerful, have a look at [all the placeholder options](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). It is, however, intended to be phased out in favor of [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
print('The enemey gets hit for {} hitpoints'.format(damage))
```

Alternatively, you can convert the value of `damage` to a string, and concatenate strings with `+`:

```
print('The enemy gets hit for ' + str(damage) + ' hitpoints')
```

Comment: To concatenate with print, I prefer the stylistic choice of: print('The enemey gets hit for', str(damage), 'hitpoints')

Comment: @hexparrot That works as well, but it requires an understanding of varargs and is not universally portable as it requires `print` to be a function to get the expected output. Also, concatenation is a universal concept, which is useful outside of printing.

Comment: @phihag Sorry, I am not a native speaker, so I may sound a bit rough sometimes. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Looks much nicer this way. ;0)

```
damage = 10
print(f'The enemey gets hit for {damage} hitpoints')
```

(for python 3.6 & above)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `hitpoints` to your string:

```
print('the enemy gets mutilated for %d hitpoints!' % damage)
```

Comment: `%d` is the format specifier for an integer, not fileobject?! http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: You're right, I confused %d for fp decimal (%f instead), which is surely not what I intended.

Comment: Well, the python docs call them integer decimals %i and floating-point decimals, which seems to me a confusing naming convention, as integers have neither a decimal point nor decimal values. %d immediately struck me as decimal related (which it is), but just not in the sense I expected.  Fileobjects were never part of the solution, you may have confused fp with fo?

Comment: Numbers in base 10 are by definition "decimal values." The part of a number after the decimal point is "the fraction," not "the decimal." Would the portion of a binary number after the binary point be called "the binary"? I think not.

Comment: I feel like the mistake has now been appropriately addressed, acknowledged, and remedied. I don't believe this much explanation was necessary for a simple confusion that 'd' was the same as 'i', and not the 'f' I thought it meant.