# print error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: python

following line gives me headaches:

print 'Total paid ' + round(totalPay, 2)

gives out an error description: "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects". According to  discussion here: [Python printing text after printing a variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333245/python-printing-text-after-printing-a-variables)

the line should be correct. Any hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Giving you headaches? A simple Google search would have given you the answer immediately.

Comment: I did not manage to find the answer by a simple google search. i really spend time on trying to find a solution. notice that in my question, i referred to another discussion. i am very new to python however. hope my abilities to solve such problems without posting questions will improve soon.

Comment: @user3774540 what on earth did you search for?! Just using the error message `"cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float'"` got me 17k results, including the duplicate I just closed this with.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
print 'Total paid ' + str(round(totalPay, 2))
```

or

```
print 'Total paid ', round(totalPay, 2)
```